# LWC how to save variables on server side, can I use session?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, lightning-web-components

I want to save variable on server side (not in database).
In Visualforce page we use Apex Controller and we can use session, can I use session in Lightning Web Components?

Comment: Hi Alexandr, in lightning aura or web component the state has to be maintained on client side; as all calls are static by design storing variable on server side is not possible. I am afraid that session may not be used for this type of caching. What are you trying to achieve in your use case?

Comment: Thank you for answer, I want to save custom object without store in database. If 
 user fills special field - I insert it to database, it will one dml operation.

Look! Maybe I can create session with public REST Api ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to store data not in a table(Dirty object) on server side.

Had it been client-side, I would have recommended, cookies for <4KB, or Local Storage for up to 5MB storage.

But you want to store in server-side, so that its browser and device-independent as data is fetched from the server.

I would look into [Session Platform Cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_session_examples.htm).

You can set and retrieve value in APEX and pass it on client side

```
// Add a value to the cache
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse('06/16/2015 11:46 AM');
Cache.Session.put('ns1.partition1.orderDate', dt);
if (Cache.Session.contains('ns1.partition1.orderDate')) {
    DateTime cachedDt = (DateTime)Cache.Session.get('ns1.partition1.orderDate');
}
```

Retrive Value back:

```
// Get a cached value
Object obj = Cache.Session.get('ns1.partition1.orderDate');
// Cast return value to a specific data type
DateTime dt2 = (DateTime)obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using session cookies to have items in the browser.

https://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/session-cookies-used-for.html

There is a good answer on SFSE already:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/270327/55914